# How to measure the time of an event in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

If there is some event on any button such as rollover event by mouse how to measure how much time that rollover event took place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, only one rollover is fired unless yuo roll out and then back on.

So here's what I would do:

```
private var timeoutId:uint=-1;
private function onRollover(e:MouseEvent):void {
    timeoutId=setTimeout(play, 5000);
}

private function onRollout(e:MouseEvent):void {
    if(timeoutId != -1) clearTimeout(timeoutId);
}

private function play():void {
    //code to play music
}
```

and of course, onRollover and onRollout handle the respective events.

Answer (score 2):

You could time the difference between MOUSE_OVER and MOUSE_OUT.

```
var myButton:Button = new Button();
var diff:Number = 0;
var startDate:Date;

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    startDate = new Date();
});

myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
    diff = (new Date()).time - startDate.time;
    if (diff >= 5000)
         // do something
});
```

I do not have Flash Builder up but this should be a good start.  Check out these docs for more info:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html#time

Comment: I need the button to play music if the mouse was kept on it for more than 5 seconds. Then there is no MOUSE_OUT.

Comment: @siddharth Try this link.  'MOUSE_OUT' is defined as mouseOut. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Button.html#eventSummary

Comment: @siddharth My previous link points toward the MOUSE_OUT property. See this link: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:mouseOut

Comment: until i roll out my mouse from the button the button does not do anything

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should take a look at the **[Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html)** class. Here's a simple example of what you can do with it:

```
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5000,1);

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, playVideo);

btnInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, 
                             function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
                                timer.start();
                             });

btnInstance.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, 
                             function(evt:MouseEvent):void {
                                timer.stop(); 
                             });

function playVideo(evt:TimerEvent):void {
    // play video
}
```

Hope it helps.